# mod_wsgi django not working with Apache24

Tags: python-3.x, django, windows, apache, mod-wsgi

I am using a MS Windows 11 Machine running Python 3.11 with `virtualenv` package installed.

I am using `Apache24` `httpd.exe` web server for my `django` app production server.

My app is called `mysite` and it is fully functional inside a virtual environment (called `venv`) with the folowing packages (requirements.txt):

```
django
django-extensions
django-iprestrict
mod-wsgi
Pillow
pyOpenSSL
odfpy
werkzeug
whitenoise
pandas
plotly
matplotlib
```

I can fully run the server in DEBUG mode with the virtual environment activated:

```
(venv) python.exe manage.py runserver
```

And, on the other hand, I was able to make the `Apache` web server to run a test website without problems.

The issue is when I edit `httpd.conf` files to integrate with my django app thorugh `mod_wsgi`:

```
# httpd.conf

(...)

LoadFile "C:/Users/myuser/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/python311.dll"
LoadModule "C:/Users/myuser/mysite/mysite_venv/venv/Lib/site-packages/mod_wsgi.cp311-win_amd64.pyd"

WSGIScriptAlias / C:\Users\myuser\mysite\mysite\wsgi.py
WSGIPythonHome C:\Users\myuser\mysite\mysite_venv\venv
WSGIPythonPath C:\Users\myuser\mysite

<Directory />
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>

# media files hosting

Alias /media "C:/Users/myuser/mysite/media/"

<Directory "C:/Users/myuser/mysite/media/">
Require all granted
</Directory>

(...)
```

My directory tree is:

```
.
├── mainapp
│   ├── admin.py
│   ├── apps.py
│   ├── forms.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── migrations
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── static
│   ├── templates
│   ├── tests.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── views.py
├── mainapp.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── media
├── mysite
│   ├── asgi.py
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
├── mysite_venv
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── venv
└── staticfiles
    ├── admin
    ├── css
    ├── django_extensions
    ├── font
    ├── icon
    ├── javascript
    ├── js
    └── uploads
```

The issue is when I run `httpd.exe` the web page loads forever because the server does not respond the client.

I have opened the `error.txt` log file from `Apache` to find out what is going on, but there was any error message about anything.

I took care about:

- setting `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to the  DLLs as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-so-it-finds-my-modules-packages)
- natively compile and place the `mod_wsgi` `.pyd` in the correct path.

Can someone help me what is going on? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did just run into a similar issue using Python 11 and Apache 2.4.

The reason why you don't see any error in the log is simply the fact that the Apache **httpd.exe**  does not start at all. If you try to run the **httpd.exe** from the console you will propably see the error displayed.

In my case the I got:

> httpd.exe: Syntax error on line 192 of C:/Apache24/conf/httpd.conf:
> Cannot load c:/python311/python311.dll into server: %1 is no
> Win32-application.

The reason at the end was: By chance I did download a 32 bit distribution of Apache but using the 64bit Version of Python 3.11 .

Downloading and installing the 64 bit Apache24 Version did solve my issue.

Make sure that you use the same: 32bit or  64bit for Apache 2.4 and Python 3.11.

Answer (score 0):

There is some issue/conflict between modules `plotly` and `mod_wsgi` that stucks the HTTP/S requests when Apache24 loads the `plotly` module through WSGI.

The same thing happens with `pandas` module, too.

I could fix this problem by commenting all `views` and `urls` that loads these modules.

There is no problem about `virtualenv` having these modules installed, the issue is that they cannot be loaded by `mod_wsgi`.

The big question is that the development server works with them through `python manage.py runserver`, the issue is exactly when you put the server in production mode.